# How to merge two matrix with duplicate dimensions in R?

Tags: r, matrix, merge

I have two matrices.
One is following:

[image]

[image]

and the other is:

[image]

[image]

How can I merge two matrices, based on their low and column names (keys)?

I tried the following code:

```
merged_matrix <- merge(matrix1, matrix2, by.x = "row.names", all = TRUE)
```

but it does not merge, two matrices and simply add more columns like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of data. They are impossible to cut and paste to recreate your issue - either just copy the plain text or use `dput(objectname)` to get reproducible R code.

Comment: [You should not post code or sample data as an image because...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1422451)

Comment: Seems like you might be better off using `cbind(matrix1, matrix2)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge matrices using merge like you planned. First, if you want to merge by column names, then you need to use something that will access column names. Simply cite the matrix and the column names you're interested in (instead of rownames) and it's smooth sailing (see example code below).

Cheers,

```
m1 = round(matrix(c(rnorm(9, mean = 2)), nrow = 3, ncol = 3), digits = 2)
m2 = round(matrix(c(rnorm(9, mean = 2)), nrow = 3, ncol = 3), digits = 2)

colnames(m1) <- c(letters[1:3])
colnames(m2) <- rev(colnames(m1))

merge(m1,m2, by.x = colnames(m1), all = TRUE)

# > print(m1)
#       a    b    c
# [1,]  1.31 3.27 2.73
# [2,] -0.57 2.35 1.61
# [3,]  0.70 3.10 0.77
#
# > print(m2)
#       c    b    a
# [1,] -0.58 1.62 1.11
# [2,]  2.34 3.22 4.40
# [3,]  1.26 1.19 1.88
#  
# > merge(m1,m2, by.x = colnames(m1), all = TRUE)
#     a    b     c
# 1 -0.57 2.35  1.61
# 2  0.70 3.10  0.77
# 3  1.11 1.62 -0.58
# 4  1.31 3.27  2.73
# 5  1.88 1.19  1.26
# 6  4.40 3.22  2.34
```